# updateOn doesnt work Reactive Forms Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

Im trying to show the validation message when I type, however it appears only when the input looses focus
I tried the following:

```js
form: FormGroup = new FormFroup({
    direction: new FormControl("", {
    validators:[Validation.required,Validation.pattern("^[0-9]*$")],
    updateOn: 'change'
}
```

in the html I dont subscribe to the (change) - maybe this is the problem- if so what do I need to do to get the validation on typing change ?

Comment: by default it is on change 

Comment: so in order to update the validation message while typing I need to subscribe to the change event and call updateValueAndvalidity ?

Comment: no you just need to check from errors

Comment: I check and they appear only on blur..(when I lose focus out of the input)

Comment: That's probably because your template only shows then once the form control has been touched.

Comment: thanks this was the issue

Answer (score 1):

by defualt the validator will run on control value change

```
  form: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    direction: new FormControl(null, {
       validators: [Validators.required, Validators.pattern("^[0-9]*$")]
    })
  });
```

and if you want to check the validation errors to display a message you can check errors if it has a value and hasError method to check a certain error

template

```html
<div [formGroup]="form">
  <input formControlName="direction">
  <div *ngIf="form.get('direction').errors">
      <div *ngIf="form.get('direction').hasError('required')">required </div>
      <div *ngIf="form.get('direction').hasError('pattern')">pattern  </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

check this demo  [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4zrcab)